# C++ UART idle time between two requests

Tags: c++, uart, termios

I am using a linux environment and using termios.h function to communicate on UART with other ECU.(electronic control unit, consider it as a computer on other end of UART).

The other ECU have put a condition that between the stop bit of last request(it can contain multiple frames in one request)and start bit of the new request there should be time difference of 1ms.

So basically i want a 1ms time between two write call but i dont want to put unnecessary sleep after every write call.

Is there any setting in UART to do this? I have added c++ as was thunking some type of flag needs to bet set while configuring UART through c++ code.

What i have tried is lock a mutex then do the write after write completes start a timer,when timer expires unlock that mutex. But what i learned is the behaviour would be undefined as when timer expires then it would the logic on a separate thread which has never acquired the mutex lock.

I cant put sleep after write beacause as soon as write finishes i need to inform the above layers by returning the function.

Comment: How i that question related to [tag:c++]? Do you have any specific c++ code you already tried? Generally that kind of stuff is beyond the realm of standard c++ facilities.

Comment: ECU? Extreme Computation Unit?

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't recall the meaning of ECU.  What is meaning of ECU?

Comment: Some sort of control unit and it might be speaking modbus RTU or a related protocol. Typically the answer is no. UARTs are dumb as a post. They buffer and send and receive and buffer. That's all they do. Timing required for anything other than making sure the bits wind up in the right byte is usually handled by a higher level controller.

Comment: Typical solution if you don't have controller hardware: Place the sending inside another thread. When a complete message is sent, the thread blocks for at least one message break time, then looks to see if more messages have been queued. [I'd use a message loop for this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), but that might be the embedded C programmer in me talking.

Comment: Edited to give more info.